# How do I highlight virtual functions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

When I am looking at a header file I would like to be able to tell, at a glance, which functions are virtual and which are not.

Is there a way, without using add-ins as I have the Express version, that I can set this up?

For example, I have used the 'Fonts and Colors' option to change the color of member functions, local variables etc. so I can easily see at a glance which is which.  I would like to do the same with virtual functions.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I work on Visual Studio, though not on Visual C/C++)

Unfortunately there is no syntax-highlighting option for virtual methods. The only thing I can suggest is that your team adopt the `override` specifier keyword, which was introduced in C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

However I don't believe there is a compiler option which makes this specifier mandatory.